# Obtaining a vector of words within a string beginning with a pattern - R

Tags: r

I want to get a vector of the words within a string in R that begins with `` $`GPE ``. 
This is what I tried:

```
grep(pattern = "$`GPE", x = GPE_string, value = TRUE)
```

However it returned: `character(0)`

Comment: An example `GPE_string` would be helpful.

Comment: Ok I actually found out GPE_string is not a string. It's a S4 (not sure what that is even). But does anyone have a solution now with that information?

Comment: I found out what I was looking for was ls(GPE_string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `str_extract_all` in `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(GPE_string, "(\\$`GPE.+?)\\b")
```

Explanation:

- The `$` in the pattern needs to be escaped with `\\`
- The part enclosed in `(...)` will be extracted
- `\\b` means word boundary, and `.+?` means one or more characters

The result of `str_extract_all` is a list of vectors,
for each string in the input vector.

Answer (score 0):

You need escape characters.

Try

```
grep(pattern="\$\`GPE", x=GPE_string, value=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hm. Error: '\$' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\$"

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking for the words that start with "$`GPE", you can do:

```
GPE_string[startsWith(GPE_string, "$`GPE")]
```

So for example,

```
> GPE_string<- c("$`GPE_Hello", "$`GPEWorld", "Hello", "World")
> GPE_string
[1] "$`GPE_Hello" "$`GPEWorld"  "Hello"       "World"    
> GPE_string[startsWith(GPE_string, "$`GPE")]
[1] "$`GPE_Hello" "$`GPEWorld"
```